# hadoop : reduce output records=0

Tags: hadoop

I am  writing MapReduce code with 2 mapper class and a reducer , but I don't know why I have an reduce output records=0. 
Please tell me how to solve this problem

```
package reducesidejoin;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

    public class ReduceSideJoinReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable,
            Text, IntWritable, Text> {
        @Override
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values,
                           Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String output = null;
            Text achat;
            Text vins;
            Text valeur2;
            Text valeur1;
            Iterator<Text> itr = values.iterator();
            valeur1 = itr.next();
            if (valeur1.charAt(0) == 1) {
                vins = valeur1;
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    valeur2 = itr.next();
                    if (valeur2.charAt(0) == 2) {
                        achat = valeur2;
                        output = vins.toString() + achat.toString();
                        context.write(key, new Text(output));
                    }
                    context.write(key, new Text(output));
                }
            } else if (valeur1.charAt(0) == 2) {
                achat = valeur1;
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    valeur2 = itr.next();
                    if (valeur2.charAt(0) == 1) {
                        vins = valeur2;
                        output = vins.toString() + achat.toString();
                        System.out.println(key + "," + output);
                    }
                    context.write(key, new Text(output));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please write clean code, so developers can help you faster and better

Comment: How are you writing to `Reducer` ? can you add Mappers code here ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way your reducer can output anything is if your char comparisons are working. This is assuming you actually have records entering your reducer.

I would have a look at these lines: `valeur1.charAt(0) == 1`

You're comparing an integer to a char and i suspect your looking for the printable value of `1` (49 if you did an integer comparison) so you probably want:

`valeur1.charAt(0) == '1'`

You're also doing this a lot - `vins = valeur1;` which is going to cause problems because hadoop is going to be reusing the `Text` objects it gives you via the `Iterable`.

You should change these to `vins.set(valeur1);`